# Would changing the radiator of an AIO cooled GPU with a bigger one improve cooling?

Tags: graphics-cards, cooling

I have an AIO watercooled GPU (MSI SeaHawk X GTX1080) that has been struggling with temperatures for a while.

The temperature problem isn't alarming for now, but as time passes and newer games come out it even though I never aim for more than 1080p60 it has been harder and harder to keep temperatures below 60/65°C.

In recent games it has become very common for temperatures to slowly rise of around 1°C every 10/15 minutes and to end up surpassing 70°C if I don't allow the card to rest and the water to cool down every once in a while by alt-tabbing or closing the game.

I know 70°C is usually perfectly OK for a GPU but with the AIO being a closed system and all I really don't like for the water to be so close to boiling temperatures, especially since temperatures never really stabilize: the hotter they get the slower they rise, but they never stop rising.

[image: MSI SeaHawk X GTX1080]

As you can see the GPU is connected to a tiny 120mm single-fan radiator, would changing it with a bigger one (maybe a 240mm dual-fan one or even a 360mm one with 3 fans) improve cooling and help stabilize the GPU's temperature?

Comment: I don't think you need to worry that much about the temperature. 70°C is well below the 83°C limit that Nvidia GPUs are set to (which is in turns well below the 94°C operating limit). If the GPU surpasses that limit, the GPU will automatically slow down. Since the liquid can't possibly get hotter than the heating source (the GPU), it will never actually go over 83° (except maybe very slightly for a very short amount of time).

Comment: In fact, I used to play at 4K with a GTX 1080, and 83°C was pretty normal (I even manually increased that limit to 85°C to allow my GPU to run faster). Since you've been playing at 1080p, I'm not surprised you're only now running into higher temps.

Comment: @TimmyJim it definitely would be perfect for Hardware Recommendations, I had no idea it existed.
Is there a way to move the question or do I just delete it here and ask it again?

Comment: @Sogaki easiest way is probably to flag your question as "in need of mod intervention" and then request the move there, since HR is not in the default list

Comment: Keep in mind two things: 1. The liquid inside an AIO cooler isn't necessarily water. The boiling point may be well above 100°C. 2. If it is water, it actually takes a lot of energy and time in contact with the > 100°C chip to cause a phase change to steam. Boiling is not an instantaneous reaction. There is no problem running the GPU at any temperature up to the thermal limit in its specifications; That limit includes a safety margin to allow it to shut the GPU down before thermal damage happens.